# Script error searching for tools in ArcGIS 10.2.1 search window

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, error

Until I tried installing Visual Studio 6.0 and Crystal Reports 8.5 last week, my ArcGIS was working perfectly. After the installation, however, every time I try to execute any search in the search window in ArcGIS 10.2.1 (both ArcMap and ArcCatalog), I get a script error with the message *Object reference not set to instance of an object* on Line 93.

[image: Script Error on line 93 char 5]

Below is the function from the file which is causing the error described.

```js
    function DoSearch()
    {
    var st = document.getElementById("st_ID").value;
    if ((st == null) || (st.replace(/\s/g,"") == "") || (st.lenght == 0))
    {
    if(GetContextCode(currentContextOnPage) != 6)
    $('#st_ID').unbind('keypress');
    else
    {
    var autoCompStr =  getAutoCompleteStrings();
    $("#st_ID").autocompleteArray(autoCompStr.split('+'),
    {
    delay:10,
    minChars:1,
    matchSubset:1,
    
    autoFill:false,
    maxItemsToShow:15,
    width:0
    });
    }

    document.getElementById("st_ID").focus();
    return;
    }

    var context = GetContextCode(currentContextOnPage);
    window.external.DoSearch(st, context); // <-- Error line
    }
```

The following are things I tried that did not yield any positive result:

- Uninstalled Visual Studio 6.0 and Crystal Reports
- Uninstalled and then reinstalled ArcGIS
- Replacing the `MdDlgContent.xsl` and `MdDlgHelp.xsl` files with the contents of `ver10.zip` file as described in ESRI KB38099 [here](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38099).
- Updated my Java RE to the latest available this morning (Java 7 update 60 v7.0.600)
- Installed all Windows Updates for Internet Explorer
- Reset all Internet Explorer settings
- Allow execution of all scripts

Surprisingly tool windows are not affected and I am able to run tools when I double click on them from the toolbox. The screen shot below shows the Buffer tool opened and displaying properly.

[image: Buffer tool window]

### How do I fix this error?

Comment: try deleting the temp file referenced in the error

Comment: It makes no difference. It is a temporary file. A new one is generated every time ArcMap is run and deleted automatically when closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I could not get any fix for this issue, I wrote an ArcGIS extension for searching for tools. I may extend it to enable searching for other things besides tools in future.

It is available for download from [Tool Finder v1.0-beta](https://github.com/franzalex/ArcGisExtensions/releases/tag/v1.0-beta).

Answer (score 1):

The error is very reminiscent, but perhaps not identical, to one that I encountered, a few years ago, and that I am not convinced has ever been resolved.

It is discussed on the **[ArcGIS Discussion Forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/13088-Running-tools-from-Search-window-gives-Webpage-Error-on-some-machines)**:

> I've seen an error thrown by two tools (Create Raster Catalog and Clip
>   - but which tools is probably irrelevant) on three Windows XP laptops using a procedure that works fine on three other Windows XP laptops
>   and two Windows Vista laptops.
>
> It occurs after the Search tool (with Tools option) is used to find a
>   tool and then the tool is left clicked on to try and start it.
>
> Instead of starting it the error seen is:
>
> "Webpage Error
>
> Contains errors that might prevent it from displaying
>   correctly
>
> ...
>
> Line: 14
>
> Error: Invalid Pointer"

I recommend that you report this one to your local **[Esri Support](http://support.esri.com/en/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Possible answer here. Worked for me.
https://gisnuts.com/terra/blog/2013/01/22/arcgis-geoprocessing-tools-scripting-error

Comment: Thanks for digging this up. I however can't verify this solution because I have since upgraded to ArcGIS 10.3.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution for this problem.

What you need to do is the following:
In Windows go to: Control Panel -> Programs -> Unistall a program. Then right click on "ArcGIS for Desktop" -> Select "Uninstall/change". The ArcGIS Setup dialog will pop up. Chose the "Repair" option.

After finishing the Repair procedures the ArcGIS will be working properly!